# Junit test cases running some test cases parallel and some sequentially

Tags: junit, parallel-processing, sequence

want to run junit test cases sequentially and parallel also. some test cases are independent so those test cases are need to run sequentially but some test cases are not dependent they have to run parallel.

is this possible through junit ? if yes how it is possible ?

Comment: i want some test cases to run sequentially and parallel..not only parllel